# What to do when user clicks back on google play games realtime multiplayer auto-match ui?

Tags: android, networking, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, multiplayer

I created a "play button" which starts the automatch UI and it begins to search for players.Once when the UI shows up, when I press back in the **automatch UI back button** ,it returns back to "play button"....But when I press it again it does nothing.
It works when I press **quit** in the automatch UI and then press **play** again

What should I be doing in code (I'm using Google play games Unity plugin) when someone presses the back button in the ui ?

**I'm working with Google play games services unity plugin**

Comment: when you press back button you need to call `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.LeaveRoom();` you can call it like : when back button pressed `if(onRoomConnected) {PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.LeaveRoom();}` onRoomConnected is a bool which will be false by default and you needs to set it to true when OnRoomConnected(bool success){} method returns success.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what your code looks like, but this is my minimal example of creating the real-time game.  I think your problem was whenever you "go back" to the play button, you need to call LeaveRoom() to reset the multi-player room state.

This is based on the SmokeTest sample in the GPGS Unity plug in project (https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity).

All the code (including this sample are covered under [Apache 2 license](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/LICENSE).

```
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.Multiplayer;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;


class SampleRTMP : MonoBehaviour, RealTimeMultiplayerListener
{
    bool canStartPlaying = true;
    bool playingGame = false;

    void Start()
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = 
            new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            // registers a callback to handle game invitations
            // received while the game is not running.
        .WithInvitationDelegate(OnInvitation)
        .Build();

        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        // recommended for debugging:
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        // Activate the Google Play Games platform
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

        // Auto login
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
            // handle success or failure
        });
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {

        if (playingGame) {
            // don't show the buttons during game play.
            return;                                                                 
        }                                                                           
        if (canStartPlaying) {                                                      
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, Screen.height / 4f, Screen.height / 8f, Screen.width / 3f), "Play")) {                                               
                canStartPlaying = false;                                            

                ulong bitmask = 0L; // no special bitmask for players               
                uint minOpponents = 1; // so the smallest is a 2 player game       
                uint maxOpponents = 1; // so the largest is a 2 player game         

                PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.CreateQuickGame(minOpponents,      
                    maxOpponents, 0, bitmask, this);                       
            }                                                                       
        } else {                                                                      
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, Screen.height / 4f, Screen.height / 12f, 100), "Leave Room")) {                                         
                PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.LeaveRoom();    
            }                                                                       
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(350, Screen.height / 4f, Screen.height / 12f, 100), "Show Waiting Room")) {                                  
                PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.ShowWaitingRoomUI();            
            }                                                                       
        }                                                                           
    }

    public void OnInvitation(Invitation invitation, bool shouldAutoAccept)
    {
        // handle the invitation
        if (shouldAutoAccept) {
            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.AcceptInvitation(invitation.InvitationId, this);
        }
        else {
            // do some other stuff.
        }
    }

    // Callbacks for Room setup
    public void OnRoomSetupProgress(float percent)
    {                                                                               
        // called once initially, then each time a player joins or leaves.          
        // or if the waiting room activity returns.                                 
        Debug.Log("Setting up room (" + ((int)percent) + "%)");  
    }

    public void OnRoomConnected(bool success)
    {                                                                               
        Debug.Log("Connected to room: " + success);                                 
        if (success) {                                                              
            // Start playing the game!                                              
            playingGame = success;                                                  
        } else {                                                                      
            // Handle error here,  then leave the room.                             
            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.LeaveRoom();                        
        }                                                                           
    }

    public void OnLeftRoom()
    {                                                                               
        Debug.Log("Left the room");                                                 
        canStartPlaying = true;                                                     
    }

    public void OnParticipantLeft(Participant participant)
    {

    }

    public void OnPeersConnected(string[] participantIds)
    {

    }

    public void OnPeersDisconnected(string[] participantIds)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }

    public void OnRealTimeMessageReceived(bool isReliable, string senderId, byte[] data)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Which method is called when the player **who is yet searching for another player to start the game** presses the back button ?